# Issue using getters and setters in p5.js javascript class, "Script error. (: line 0)"

Tags: javascript, class, setter, getter, p5.js

I have created a class which takes in an array of vector coordinates, and then sketches leafs where those coordinates are. I am writing a getter and a setter where you can change the colour of these leafs. The leaf colour rages from a minHue and a maxHue. I am getting a "Script error. (: line 0)" when running the class but cannot locate what is wrong.

I have looked through the code for any case errors but cant final any.

```
class drawLeaves {

  constructor(leafArray) {
    this.leafs = leafArray;
    this.randomColor = true;
    this.minHue = 0;
    this.maxHue = 0;
  }

  genLeaves(minDiam, maxDiam, minAlpha, maxAlpha) {

    if (this.randomColor) {
      var rdn0 = random(255);
      var rdn1 = random(255);
      this.minHue = min(rdn0, rdn1);
      this.maxHue = max(rdn0, rdn1);
    } else {
      var colors = this.leafColor;
      minHue = colors[0];
      maxHue = colors[1];
    }



    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.leafs.length; i++) {
        let h = map(i, 0, this.leafs.length, this.minHue, this.maxHue);
        let s = 255;
        let b = 255;
        let a = random(minAlpha, maxAlpha);
        fill(h, s, b, a);
        let diam = random(minDiam, maxDiam);
        let jitterX = random(-30, 30);
        let jitterY = random(-30, 30);  
        ellipse(this.leafs[i].x + jitterX, this.leafs[i].y + jitterY, diam, diam);
    }
  }



  draw() {
    this.genLeaves(0, 90, 0, 0.03);  // big leaves
    this.genLeaves(0, 15, 0, 0.25);  // small leaves

  }


  set leafColor(minHue, maxHue) {
    this.minHue = minHue;
    this.maxHue = maxHue;
    this.randomColor = false;
  }

  get leafColor() {
    return [this.minHue, this.maxHue]
  }
}
```

Looking for feedback to help remove the error, many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this in the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/en/repl.html#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAmBOYDuAZApmAbmmBvAUPtNMAPYB2EALvAK7BWnwAUIGAZgILyICeAlNALFiVABYBLCADo2YdjAC80OVx5heAbiIjxU6YnKxSAWwDCpEE2jKatNNpHQ9MkxPIAJezegAGR7qSrmAAHl5oPv46AL6ExADmaOToWDjMbuQAIhJgJgA00Cah2bkFGZwgAA5iYGWhFdVgggQ6xBLs0MwuBmBGphZW8M2tIphg8NDwsOS-PobGJswATACsK_wBTmMTU-QAjHO9C8trGyOiQdIZ4T4ZzLu-Bbt7Z04X-kVh3sqf99OPk2mL020Gi0DQIAgEWEb22JEsTCUzkuqgGTBBxGu33hgwgAG1fABdDGFUI3ZRkXF4vbEkaxQgjNhUaASEHsazMCSRTQs6AAHmR-lUMjY5Hi4h5EgA1FLhm8REzoGJbmBKpyCgDusLZElxWICt0sWgDZdPuFXvKVGhmUjVisScRFQAjHx2h1W5lgQ59RblKo1OohBo1C3y9gSEAgZj66AQApOgpNd2K2A5Eze44ZEr5UkhbOht6KgBWEioVDQ8AAGhnTMwALQAZgBTYLTmLpfL8AAmjXFo3m74NsRziIISAJJUoV0URx8RJCdIQtApdAS2WK5WTULZ3j59JeMvVx2K12CqnSnA0wXYsR6XE4IgkMw5YF9IlkhhsBBmACAJwAgDpF8Bsh2gAB6MDoCdCR4itVIIBGbp3xSL8fwKPYVg1DVpFWUCINjIpIzgr97zvYgoWZVEERYI1A3NIRENNdxyUKZj7BBQ0yWxM12MY_R5n6aifHYMBIQcGJ70SSiODRFgX2IeBrVoeByGgPFDTY41BWCL40EJHQgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=) I get the following error:

```
repl: setter should have exactly one param (48:2)
```

According to the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Description) a setter should only have 1 parameter.

Try refactoring so you can have only 1 parameter or change it to this:

```
setLeafColor(minHue, maxHue) {
    code
}
```